# Why Nuxt 3 Not Updating Realtime Upon Data Change on Props?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

i have this problem in which the HTML page is not updating upon props variables change. Please help me.

I make a table in my child element based on the array passed by the parent, here is the child code:

```
      <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Blank</th>
                <th>Error</th>
                <th>Warning</th>
                <th>Clean</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(datae, index) in props.ranking" :key="index">
                    <td>{{ index }}</td>
                    <td>{{ '(' + datae.username + ') ' + datae.realname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ datae.blank }}</td>
                    <td>{{ datae.error }}</td>
                    <td>{{ datae.warning }}</td>
                    <td>{{ datae.clean }}</td>
                    <td>{{ datae.total }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
       </table>
```

Here is the child script:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

    var props = defineProps({
        ranking: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
        }
    })

    watch(() => props.ranking, (newValue, oldValue) => console.log('tes'))
</script>
```

I am expecting the html table update upon props.ranking change

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: How is it updated btw?

Comment: I can't see the data change in the devtools though since it is nuxt 3, and not using data() anymore

Comment: It is updated by the parent element when a button pressed, the ranking suppose to change and change the table in the child component @kissu

Comment: Of course you can, it is still a Vue3 app with all the events/props visible. Check that you have the latest stable devtools installed.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a couple of issues here. It might help you.

First of all, you used the `props` keyword in the template, it's not needed.

```html
<!-- props.ranking -> ranking -->
<tr v-for="(datae, index) in ranking" :key="index">
  <td>{{ index }}</td>
  <td>{{ '(' + datae.username + ') ' + datae.realname }}</td>
  <td>{{ datae.blank }}</td>
  <td>{{ datae.error }}</td>
  <td>{{ datae.warning }}</td>
  <td>{{ datae.clean }}</td>
  <td>{{ datae.total }}</td>
</tr>
```

The second point is that you watch an array prop, but it isn't changed, only the properties (items) of this array will be changed. So your watcher callback never fires. To fix this, you can pass the `deep` option to watch as a third argument, like this:

```js
watch(() => props.ranking,
  (newValue, oldValue) => console.log('tes'),
  { deep: true }
)
```

[Source: watch arrays](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/watch.html)